# i18n Angular, error by creating translation files

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

In my app all works correctly and I can execute each component or function without any error, so in terminal, as in the developer console of the browser. I tried to install the i18n internationalization by the following command:

```
ng xi18n --output-path src/locale
```

The file creates itself correctly but I see this strange error.

```
Cannot assign to read only property '_showWarnings' of object '#<Object>'
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_showWarnings' of object '#<Object>'
    at TapSubscriber._visitJsonRecursive.pipe.operators_1.tap.x [as _tapNext] (C:\Users\myname\Documents\Projekt\myProjekt\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\visitor.js:56:210)
```

Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happened to me. after I upgraded the packet `angular-devkit/build-angular`. On version `0.803.2` it worked totally fine. Since `npm audit` warned me about vulnerabilities I updated this packet to version `0.803.23`. This lead to exactly the error you are describing.

I did not find a proper solution yet, but for now the following **workaround** does the job:

Remove your `node_modules` folder, downgrade the packet, run `npm install`, run `ng xi18n --output-path src/locale` and drop the changes on `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and `package.json` again.

**Edit**

Updating all the @angular related packages to the latest 8.x version solved the problem for me.

Comment: @sevic, you just made my day! I didn't need to do the whole "Remove your node_modules" stuff, `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.2 --save-dev` was enough

Comment: yep of course that works. the reason why i wrote all that "drop the changes on the packets again" stuff is, to still keep the latest `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version :)